# How do I select rows that match any value inside an array in supabase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, supabase, supabase-database

I want to select all rows that match at least one of given tags from this table:

[image]

If I want to search by tag1 and tag3 it should return 1st, 3rd and 4th row
and when I want to search by tag2 and tag4 it should return all of them because they all have this tag
and if I want to search by tag4 it should return just 2nd row.

I found how to select ones that have all the tags provided which is:

```
.select().contains("tags", ["tag1", "tag2"])
```

but the returned rows meet all two tags at once so it returns just 2nd and 3rd row and I want it to return 4th row as well.

Comment: Array.some() is one such function which return true if there is at least one element matching. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) documentation

Comment: I would rather know how to do it straight from supabase but I think it will do just fine if I make the logic behind it good enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match any value of that array, then you need to encapsulate it within the OR filter:

```js
const supabase = createClient(SUPABASE_URL, SUPABASE_KEY);
const { data: ret, error } = await supabase
  .from('test_tags')
  .select()
  .or('tags.cs.{tag1}','tags.cs.{tag2}');
  
console.log(ret);
```

You can also expand and use two or more `OR` logical operators:

```js
const { data: ret, error } = await supabase
  .from('test_tags')
  .select()
  .or('tags.cs.{tag1},or(tags.cs.{tag4},tags.cs.{tag3})');
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(ret));
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you're looking for the `overlap` filter
https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/overlaps

```
const { data, error } = await supabase
  .from('your_table')
  .select()
  .overlaps('tags', ['tag1', 'tag2'])
```